# Selecting specific rows in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, row

Sample data:

```
dat <- structure(list(value = c(860L, 860L, 835L, 835L, 870L, 820L, 820L, 850L, 850L, 810L,
                                 852L, 840L, 840L, 825L, 825L, 900L, 900L, 830L,
                                 830L, 865L, 865L, 822L, 822L, 882L, 882L, 867L, 867L, 725L,
                                 725L, 727L, 727L, 874L, 874L), 
                  loc.id = c(12L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 12L,
                             13L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 
                             13L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 13L)), 
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -33L))

dat <- dat %>% dplyr::arrange(loc.id, value)

dat <- dat %>% dplyr::group_by(loc.id) %>% dplyr::mutate(length.val = n()) %>% dplyr::mutate(points.l = ceiling(length.val/4))
```

For each loc.id, I want to select 4 rows which should be indexed as (using example of loc.id == 12):
1) first row which is the row number,
2) row which is  first row + points.l which in case of loc.12 is 6th row,
3) row which is last row - points.l which in case of loc.12 is the 12th row (17 - 5)
4) the last row which is the row number 17. Something like:

```
  dat %>% group_by(loc.id) %>% 
            dplyr::filter(row_number() == 1st row,
                          row_number() == 1st row + points.l,
                          row_number() == last row - points.l,
                          row_number() == last row)
```

Comment: Are you thinking of `dat %>% group_by(loc.id) %>% dplyr::filter(row_number() == 1 | row_number() == 1 + points.l | row_number() == n() - points.l | row_number() == n())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply :

```
 dat %>% group_by(loc.id) %>% filter(row_number() %in% c(1,1+points.l,n()-points.l,n()))
```